# Encryption of data in SQL Server containing complex SP and used by Spring Apllication

Tags: sql-server, spring, jpa, encryption

Please recommend a good encryption method for SQL Server data/column encryption, which is also compatible with complex Stored Procedures, should be able to implement in both LINUX and Windows.

I have tried using Always encrypted feature, but there are some limitations which cannot be used in complex SP, such as like, substring operations don't work.

Another approach was to use the EncryptByPassPhrase, DecryptByPassPhrase. But limitation here is passphrase/key needs to be hardcoded in the entity class.Is there a way to pass the passphrase dynamically through property to Spring jpa entity classes.

Any other technology also is welcome, which is compatible with the AWS

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a website for asking for application and tool recommendations, it is a Q&A website specifically about programming (and similar) languages, and applications that are closely related to them (I.e. Visual Studio). If you have a programming question, please do ask one, otherwise this question will very likely be closed as off-topic and/or downvoted. Thanks.

Comment: @Lamu, while the question is badly worded, I believe it is a valid question and not a bad one (OP did his homework). He is asking for a suggestion on how to do encryption in SQL Server for an existing DB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clearly understand your encryption goals, specifically, who are you protecting data against.

A general encryption at rest can be achieved using [TDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-2017). This method encrypts database files and backups, defending against a casual database theft while allowing all authorised users to see the data. This is an Enterprise Edition feature.

If you need to prevent some authorised users (e.g. developers/DBA) from seeing restricted data while still allowing them to query the database and you have SQL 2016 or later, there is [Data Masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-2017) solution. While it does not encrypt data it effectively prevents certain users from seeing it. Combined with TDE method above it is, in my opinion, the easiest method to protect your data without requiring major rewrites of your SPs.

The 3rd alternative is more time consuming to implement but works on earlier versions of SQL Server and does not require Enterprise edition.
If you need to prevent some authorised users (e.g. developers) from seeing the actual data while still allowing them to query the database you can implement the solution described in https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3081/using-views-to-expose-encrypted-data-in-sql-server/ and https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2840/sql-server-encryption-to-block-dbas-data-access/ . For practical and performance reasons this will only work if you need to encrypt few columns in a few tables.

Sample "demo" code is below. Note that `INSTEAD OF` triggers have some limitations (e.g. they don't return `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`). Also note that I am not using `DecryptByPassPhrase` but`DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOASYMKEY`.

```
-- Assuming you have existing table tCust with the following definition
CREATE TABLE tCust( ID INT IDENTITY, Name VARCHAR( 200 ), Addr1 VARCHAR( 200 ), Addr2 VARCHAR( 200 ))

INSERT INTO tCust( Name, Addr1, Addr2 )
SELECT 'A', 'A1', 'A2' UNION
SELECT 'B', 'B1', 'B2'

-- Create Keys
--If there is no master key, create one now.   
IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE symmetric_key_id = 101 )  
    CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY   
    PASSWORD = 'somepass'  
GO

CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY AsymKeyCustData WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_2048;

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SymKeyCustData
    WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256,
        KEY_SOURCE = 'PassPhrase', 
        IDENTITY_VALUE = 'IdentityPhrase' 
        ENCRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY AsymKeyCustData;

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymKeyCustData DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY AsymKeyCustData;
SELECT ID, Name,
    ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('SymKeyCustData'), Addr1 ) AS Addr1,
    ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('SymKeyCustData'), Addr2 ) AS Addr2
INTO tCustEncrypted
FROM tCust
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymKeyCustData;

EXEC sp_rename 'tCust', 'tCustOLD'

GO
CREATE VIEW tCust
AS
    SELECT ID, Name,
        CONVERT( VARCHAR( 100 ), DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('AsymKeyCustData'), NULL, Addr1 )) AS Addr1,
        CONVERT( VARCHAR( 100 ), DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('AsymKeyCustData'), NULL, Addr2 )) AS Addr2
    FROM tCustEncrypted
GO
CREATE TRIGGER tr_vCust ON tCust
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymKeyCustData DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY AsymKeyCustData;

    INSERT INTO tCustEncrypted
    SELECT Name,
        ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('SymKeyCustData'), Addr1 ) AS Addr1,
        ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('SymKeyCustData'), Addr2 ) AS Addr2
    FROM inserted

    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymKeyCustData;

RETURN;
GO

-- Encrypted Data
SELECT * FROM tCustEncrypted

-- View replaces original table
SELECT * FROM tCust

INSERT INTO tCust( Name, Addr1, Addr2 )
SELECT 'C', 'C1', 'C2'

SELECT * FROM tCust
```